# Zentyal AD logon script

Tags: authentication, samba, zentyal

I've Zentyal 4.2 domain controller server.
I would like to reach that when users login to Windows, mount some network drives automatically with logon script.
(just only those drives where the user have permission)

The users profiles store in /home/samba/profiles/ and the users home's directory in /home/`<username>`.

This is my smb.conf netlogon parts:

```
logon path = \%L\samba\profiles\%U
logon home = \%L\%U
logon script = logon.bat
[netlogon]
path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/domain.local/scripts
browseable = no
read only = yes
```

I put the logon.bat and `<username>`.bat files to the followed directories:

```
/var/lib/samba/sysvol/domain.local/scripts
/home/samba/profiles/<username>
/home/<username>
```

But didn't work...

Can you help me?

(sorry for my English)

Comment: The windows command for mounting a network storage is `NET USE Z: \\domain.local\path`. Check with **`dsa.msc`** if the logon script for the user is set correctly.